# Does OpenID Connect requires additional libraries on top of OAuth?

Tags: c#, oauth, openid, saml, openid-connect

I have Identity Server used for SSO, which compatible with OAuth 2.0 and SAML.

Also, I have API Gateway which requires URL for OpenID Connect issuer.

How can I establish a friendship between them without any middleware?

Answer (score 0):

IdentityServer 4 supports OpenID Connect (OIDC) and OIDC is a superset of oAuth.

Comment: In my case it is a customer Identity Server, which implements only SAML and OAuth

Comment: In that case, yes, you'll need a different and/or additional libraries.